# Apache: rewrite rule with variable data

Tags: apache-httpd, mod-rewrite

I need make this redirect to my webserver:

`www.hostname.com/path1/path2/123456789` to `www.hostname.com/search?q=123456789`

I have inserted this rule to htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^/path1/path2/([0-9]+)$ /search?q=$1 [L,R=301]
```

but is doesn't work (the number is a variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a .htaccess file, you should not have a leading slash: "the per-directory prefix (which always is the same for a specific directory) is automatically removed for the RewriteRule pattern matching and automatically added after any relative (not starting with a slash or protocol name) substitution".

I don't know in which directory your .htaccess lives, but you should remove the prefix for that directory:

```
RewriteRule ^path1/path2/([0-9]+)$ /search?q=$1 [L,R=301]
```

… or …

```
RewriteRule ^path2/([0-9]+)$ /search?q=$1 [L,R=301]
```

… or …

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /search?q=$1 [L,R=301]
```